# Deadlock on insert trigger when creating DB partition - Sometimes

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, database-partitioning

I have a table A. and some other tables B, C and D.

B, C and D are partitioned by the value of the ID column of A.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_A
(
    id uuid CONSTRAINT a_guid UNIQUE not null
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_B
(
    id uuid CONSTRAINT b_guid UNIQUE not null,
    a_id uuid NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT pk_b PRIMARY KEY (id, a_id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(a_id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_C
(
    id uuid CONSTRAINT b_guid UNIQUE not null,
    a_id uuid NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT pk_C PRIMARY KEY (id, a_id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(a_id);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_D
(
    id uuid CONSTRAINT b_guid UNIQUE not null,
    a_id uuid NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT pk_d PRIMARY KEY (id, a_id)
) PARTITION BY LIST(a_id);
```

We created those procedures in order to use them in our trigger: On insert to Table A

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION uuid2TableName(guid uuid) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN REPLACE(guid::text, '-', '_');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getPartitionedTables() RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN ARRAY['TABLE_B','TABLE_C','TABLE_D'];
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';


-- Create new partition tables on triggered

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createPartitions() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
   part_tables text[] = getPartitionedTables();
   part_id text;
   curr_table text;
BEGIN
    part_id = uuid2TableName(NEW.id);

    FOREACH curr_table IN ARRAY part_tables
    LOOP
        execute format('CREATE TABLE %s_%s PARTITION OF %s FOR VALUES IN (''%s'')', curr_table, part_id, curr_table, NEW.id);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE deletePartitions(a_id uuid) AS $$
DECLARE
   part_tables text[] = getPartitionedTables();
   part_id text;
   curr_table text;
BEGIN
    part_id = uuid2TableName(a_id::text);

    FOREACH curr_table IN ARRAY part_tables
    LOOP
        execute format('DROP TABLE %s_%s', curr_table, part_id);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The triggers are defined like this

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_new_a_id ON TABLE_A;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_new_a_id
    AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_A
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION createPartitions();

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger_delete_a_id ON TABLE_A;
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_delete_a_id
    AFTER DELETE ON TABLE_A
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE deletePartitions(ROW.id);
```

So far everything is working. Our tests are creating and deleting A rows and all good.

Once a while - we get this deadlock message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 30220 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on relation 1769359 of database 23886; blocked by process 30175.
Process 30175 waits for AccessShareLock on relation 1769283 of database 23886; blocked by process 30220.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
  Where: SQL statement "CREATE TABLE TABLE_B_1f8e4e73_2f39_455f_9bea_5730553553cd PARTITION OF TABLE_B FOR VALUES IN ('1f8e4e73-2f39-455f-9bea-5730553553cd')"
```

We develop in java, spring boot, hibernate and Postgres as DB. In the integration tests we start with a simple `java.sql.Connection` insert statement into TABLE_A - and there it crashes. I suspect that it might be connected to some asynchronization tests running in the background. But each test generates a new uuid for its IDs and unless we won the lottery and drew few times the same uuid values :S

The problem is that I can't really reproduce this error, but it happend few times in our pipeline tests, and better now solving it and not in the production.

Any suggestions, directions, ways to maybe reproduce this deadlock ?

Comment: How is multi-threading implemented? DROP TABLE locks the whole table `AccessExclusiveLock `  and conflicts with `AccessShareLock`, I doubt some multi-threading runs on to the deadlocks.

Comment: As you say `DROP TABLE` of the partition is locking the all table. But I still don't see how Resources are waiting for each other.. Can you provide an example how can it produce this deadlock?

Comment: How is multi-threading implemented? It is being managed by the tests `junit 5`. And again this case happend to us 3 times and very rare. But I would like not to ignore it